# Creating Search functionality in reactJs for Table content

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to build a search and sorting functionality for the table content. I don't want to use package as I am trying to learn and see how the react search work. I have the following that loads the content from payloads

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import '../css/about.css'; 
import Pagination from '../components/Pagination'
function About() {
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);
    const [loading , setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
    const [postsPerPage, setPostsPerPage] = useState(5);
    const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

    async function getData() 
        {
           let response = await fetch('https://api.github.com/users');
           let data = await response.json();
            // setUserData(data)
            return data;
        }
        //call getData function
        getData()
        .then(data => console.log(data)
        );//
    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true)
        getData()
        .then(
           data => {
               setUserData(data) }
        )
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
          })
    }, [])


      // Get current posts
      const indexOfLastPost = currentPage * postsPerPage;
      const indexOfFirstPost =  indexOfLastPost - postsPerPage;
      const currentPosts = userData.slice(indexOfFirstPost, indexOfLastPost);

      // changw page 
      const paginate = (pageNumber) => setCurrentPage(pageNumber);

      // Search Table 
      const handleFilterChange = e => {
          const value = e.target.value || undefined;
          if( search !== "" && userData.login.indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) === -1 ) {
            return null;
        }
            setSearch(value)
      }


    return (
        <div className="container">

                 <div>
                     <input value={search}
                     onChange={handleFilterChange}
                     placeholder={"Search"}

                     />
                     <table>
                         <thead>
                         <tr>
                             <td>id</td>
                             <td>avatar_url</td>
                             <td>events_url</td>
                             <td>followers_url</td>
                             <td>following_url</td>
                             <td>gists_url</td>
                             <td>gravatar_id</td>
                             <td>html_url</td>
                             <td>login</td>
                             <td>node_id</td>
                             <td>organizations_url</td>
                             <td>received_events_url</td>
                             <td>repos_url</td>
                             <td>site_admin</td>
                             <td>starred_url</td>
                             <td>subscriptions_url</td>
                             <td>type</td>
                             <td>url</td>
                         </tr>
                         </thead>
                         <tbody>
                         { 
             currentPosts.map((item, index) => (
                         <tr  key={index}>
                             <td>{item.id}</td>
                            <td>{item.avatar_url}</td>
                             <td>{item.events_url}</td>
                             <td>{item.followers_url}</td>
                             <td>{item.following_url}</td>
                             <td>{item.gists_url}</td>
                             <td>{item.gravatar_id}</td>
                            <td>{item.html_url}</td>
                             <td>{item.login}</td>
                             <td>{item.node_id}</td>
                             <td>{item.organizations_url}</td>
                             <td>{item.received_events_url}</td>
                             <td>{item.repos_url}</td>
                             <td>{item.site_admin}</td>
                             <td>{item.starred_url}</td>
                             <td>{item.subscriptions_url}</td>
                             <td>{item.type}</td>
                             <td>{item.url}</td>
                         </tr>
                          ))
                        }
                         </tbody>
                     </table>
                     <Pagination postsPerPage={postsPerPage} totalPosts={userData.length} paginate={paginate} />
                 </div>
            
                 
        </div>
    )
}

export default About
```

The pagination code is listed below.

```
import React from 'react'

 const Pagination = ({ postsPerPage, totalPosts, paginate }) => {
     const pageNumbers = [];
     for(let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(totalPosts / postsPerPage);  i++) {
        pageNumbers.push(i);
     } 
    return (
        <div>
            <ul className="pagination">
                {pageNumbers.map(number => (
                    <li key={number} className="page-item">
                            <a onClick={() => paginate(number)} 
                            href="#" className="page-link">
                                {number}
                            </a>
                    </li>
                ))}

            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Pagination
```

I am think because I used .map within the tbody and the search isn't affecting the content. Though I have no error, only that nothing is displaying from search parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you didn't create the function to handle the searching. You can use this generic approach which will search across the rows and the column and will match the cases.

```
function DataSearch(rows) {
        const columns = rows[0] && Object.keys(rows[0]);
        return rows.filter((row) =>
        columns.some((column) => row[column].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) > -1)
        );
    }
```

instantiate the function

```
const  searchPosts = DataSearch(currentPosts);
```

Use the searchPosts on your .map function in tbody.